# Customize Plugin

Tags: php, metabox, htmlspecialchars-decode

I am trying to create custom welcome panel in dashboard for WP and can't see where I went wrong. It's not allowing me to add html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `update_option` should be inside a hook callback and should check to see if `$_POST['custom_welcome_panel']` is set before trying to update the option. Otherwise that could be overwriting your option every time the page loads. And, honestly, as written I could shove anything I wanted into that option value. I'd just have to send a POST request to the site. It is very insecure.

Move your `update_option` into your function, check that it is set and not empty before trying to use it, and [process it like post content](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses_post), at least.

```
function custom_welcome_panel() {
    // register the setting
    if (!empty($_POST['custom_welcome_panel'])) {
        $option = wp_kses_post( $_POST['custom_welcome_panel'] );
        update_option('custom_welcome_panel', $option);
    }

    $customwelcome_panel = html_entity_decode(get_option( 'custom_welcome_panel' ));
    // the rest of your code
```

[You should also be using nonces.](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces)

It looks like you might be hacking a core file (`options.php`), which is a very bad idea if true. If so, that hack will be overwritten the next time WordPress is updated, and your code stops working.

I tried this...

```
update_option('html_test', '<p><a href="yay">Does HTML WOrK?</a></p>');
```

... and the html is inserted just fine and it come back out just fine. So I took a look at the jQuery.

The problem is here:

```
jQuery("#welcome-panel").html("'.$customwelcome_panel.'")
```

Imagine what happens with that populated by my HTML:

```
jQuery("#welcome-panel").html("<p><a href="yay">Does HTML WOrK?</a></p>")
```

Notice you have two sets of `"` now. The quotes open before the `<p>` then close after `href=` and open again after `yay`. The problem is that there are stray characters in between. The following works but only if your markup is consistent and always uses `"`s around attributes.

```
jQuery("#welcome-panel").html(\''.$customwelcome_panel.'\').delay(300).fadeTo(\'slow\', 1);
```

Using `addslashes` would be more robust:

```
jQuery("#welcome-panel").html("'.addslashes($customwelcome_panel).'").delay(300).fadeTo(\'slow\', 1);
```

I am not sure how reliable that is going to be. I only spent five minutes testing it.

Put that together and I think that should work. I am not responsible for the security of your project or for the robustness of the solution. I am hacking this together from barely sufficient information, but it is pretty basic stuff.

### Reference

http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation

Comment: @Jessica : I made some edits to the answer to move you along.